# how to make .top and .offset work together

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problems solving why my Jquery is being ignored. Below is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $root = $('html, body ');
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset.top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is the jquery i am trying to get to nicely scroll to a part of the page which almost works if I use `.offset('top')` but throws out this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in
>   top

which has made the jquery jump instead of scroll nicely.

The rest of the Jquery code:

```
// Responsive menu 
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('#pull');
        menu        = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Has anyone experienced this before and have they found a solution?

Comment: if you want to declare multiple values using a single `var` statement then you should separate them with commas, rather than semi-colons.

Comment: ...since with the semi-colons, you're ending the `var` and the next statement is just an assignment, and so you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the property `top` of the *function* `offset`:

```
$(href).offset.top
```

jQuery objects have a method [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), the result of running which has a property `.top`.
Perhaps that's what you want to use?

```
$(href).offset().top
```

I have investigated the error message and it is pretty clear that it happens in [the `setOffset` call](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cb37994d76afb45efc3b606546349ed4e695c053/src/offset.js#L64) in jQuery.
It seems that somewhere the `offset` function is being called with parameter `"top"`, which is incorrect.

Without having all of the code I can't debug further, but please check that your `scrollTo` parameter is definitely spelled out correctly and that the error really happens on that line in the code.

Comment: I have tried to use that but it throws this error; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined " and stops my responsive menu jquery below it. Any ideas/

Comment: @MaxwellLynn, in your question you claim that you tried `.offset('top')`. Note that it is different from `.offset().top`. Can you confirm that you already tried both?

Comment: Indeed i have. any ideas?

Comment: I also find the `.attr` usage confusing. Instead of `$.attr(this, 'href')`, I would suggest trying the regular `$(this).prop('href')`, although it probably is unrelated.

Comment: oh right thats handy to know. Have you got any other ideas why it wouldn't work? Maybe putting the functions into one?

Comment: Thank you, I have put together this fiddle which i should of done from the start. http://jsfiddle.net/x82mU/

Comment: Great, a fiddle is great. You've forgot to add jQuery, but I've added it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/x82mU/1/. The problem is - the demo works for me. I click on "About" and it slowly scrolls down.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should of stated that it works however my next bit of Jquery doesn't work which is the drop down menu for phones which you can see happening on this link. http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/Test/

Comment: @MaxwellLynn If it works, then isn't this question solved? If you have a new question, feel free to create a new one.